# "Agree to do something" or "agree doing something"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

User can postpone receiving notifications. 
The doer of notifying is the application not the user.
I wonder if this sentence is correct.

> Do you agree to postpone receiving this notification for 2 days?

or

> Do you agree postponing this notification for 2 days?

Comment: "agree" usually licenses infinitives (not gerunds), is it a warning notification or something?

Comment: @Cardinal Yes. It is a warning

Comment: Personally, I think warnings are more compact. Something like: "Click here to postpone receiving notifications"

Comment: @Cardinal I agree. thanks for your opinion. but the text that I should translate it to english is this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a different user-experience perspective you might consider dropping 'agree' entirely and using something like

> Do you **want** to postpone notifications for 2 days?
>   Yes / No

Typically 'agree' would be used where you want the user to consent to doing something for you.

> Do you agree to take part in a survey / receive marketing material.

Whereas 'want' would be used where the user benefits but you need to warn them about an significant change.

> Do you want to use the new password / silence notifications?

Answer (score 5):

Gerunds are typically used to talk about an instance of an activity (as a noun) that is actually happening now, has happened, or that the speaker/writer has a high confidence will happen.   Infinitives are used to talk about a possible-but-might-not-happen or desired instance of an activity.,

Here's how that would evaluate with your examples:

> Do you agree postponing this notification for 2 days?

You are in the process of receiving a notification.  Notifications are typically short and instant so this sounds weird.  "Do you agree postponing this 10GByte download for 2 days" makes more sense, for example.

> Do you agree to postpone this notification for 2 days?

You haven't seen the notification yet.  You don't know what the notification is.

Unless your notification is large where receiving it is  a long process - which is unlikely as then it would not be a mere notification - the second example is the one that most likely makes sense.

Comment: What if you change "this notification" to "next notification"? I think they already received one notification, and I construed "this" as "this sort of". Perhaps, that's why I din't notice the difference.

Comment: "Do you agree postponing the next notification for 2 days" sounds like you are expecting a notification soon or getting a steady stream of them and you want to put them on pause.  "Do you agree to postpone the next notification for 2 days" sounds like you aren't sure if you are going to get a notification, get them only occasionally, or that this is a requirement for something else.

Comment: I tried looking for "**agree + gerund**" but couldn't find any examples it seems that only "**agree + to-infinitive**" is correct.

Comment: If you want to throw a spanner in the works, how about the sentence "Do you agree to notifications being postponed for 2 days?" As far as grammar goes, there's also the structure "Do you agree to [someone] postponing this notification for 2 days?"

Comment: I'm with @SovereignSun on this. The only way agree + gerund works is if the gerund is part of a construct like "Do you agree building a sentence that way is wrong?"

Comment: @JATerroba It's just a reduced clause here "**that**" is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

"Do you agree postponing" is not correct. From a grammatical point of view, you want "Do you agree with postponing this notification." I think that is clear enough.

"Do you agree to postpone this notification" implies that the reader is the one who is expected to perform the notification, and they are being asked to postpone it. So that appears to have the wrong meaning for what you want.

Comment: As a native (US) speaker, I'd read the "do you agree to" version with the implication that I (as reader) am the one who is performing the postponing, and would not infer anything about who is expected to perform the notification.  With the inclusion of the `receiving` part, it's quite clear that I'm the one who would be receiving but am instead postponing.  I'm pretty sure that version would be clear in context, but then again maybe I'm just too used to these types of "snooze" messages...

In any case, "do you agree postponing" is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **agree to**.

### Reasoning

This is a fixed collocation of the verb "to agree". That is, "to agree to" has the precise meaning of giving consent.

### However

Note, that there are other verbs with different semantics with regard to this collocation!
 - "They stopped smoking" = They quit smoking
 -"They stopped to smoke" = They came to a halt in order to smoke

As Mark pointed out, using "postpone" might be wrong. I am not sure about this though. What language is the original?